# Misleading dupehammer message

Tags: feature-request, dupehammer

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42409297/15498) was just dupe-hammer closed.

According to the notice at the bottom, it was marked as a duplicate by myself, Jon Skeet and CodeCaster.

[image]

Of course, that's not true. All three of us are gold badge holders in the C# tag. If just *one* of us had voted to close as duplicate it would have been marked as a duplicate and closed.

One can reasonably conclude that both I and Jon Skeet chose to close for *other reasons*. So, of the three close votes, two of them weren't dupe votes.

I would suggest that when the dupehammer is applied, only the names of those who have also suggested closing as a duplicate should be included in this message. If CodeCaster had voted first, our close votes would not have been possible and our names would not be included here.

Quite apart from anything else, I think it leaves the wrong feedback for the OP. The OP only seems to get the feedback "you should have searched better" - but two of us felt that there were *other* issues with this question, that the OP will not actually learn about and correct in later questions until they ask, in their now established style, a question that isn't a duplicate.

Comment: I'd suggest using the FR-tag instead of the bug-tag, as this does seem to be "normal" (indicated by the "status-bydesign"-tag).

Comment: I've marked this as "by design"... If a question is closed by a user with a binding vote (be it the OP self closing a suggested dupe, a gold badge holder dupe hammering or a mod) - that becomes the close reason and the names of all voters are listed. If a question gets the normal requirement of five votes where not all agree, then the main reason is based on the majority  of votes, but an additional breakdown is shown with who voted for what.

Comment: As @Seth says... Maybe you want to make a FR to always do the breakdown but I'm fairly sure it's been asked before and declined.

Comment: @JonClements - okay, done.

Comment: If only Jon Skeet would have had the gold tag badge, this question could have been closed as a duplicate sooner.

Comment: @TravisJ - I think he's new here.

Comment: IIRC this kind of issue was brought up before and nothing was done. The issue was users having a problem with their name being displayed as one of the voters for a close reason they did not pick. In my opinion it should always list every close voter and their reason in the banner.

Comment: somewhat weaker feature request that was considered acceptable by SE team: [After question is closed expose close votes distinguished by reason in the timeline page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284886/165773). It also quotes a reasoning why they don't want more explicit exposure: "Throwing several reasons at them at once, especially if they're just top-level reasons without full explanations, isn't very helpful. How do you choose where to start if you see four lines of giant text screaming at you..."

Comment: For the record: I voted to close as duplicate where the duplicate target explains the reasons for **the compiler error they were getting, but omitted from the question**. I felt that duplicate would be of greater help than voting to close for off-topic: no mcve.

Comment: I think this happens because from the asker's perspective, having a question closed as a duplicate is more helpful than having it closed for any other reason - dupe closure points to a place that has the answer.

Comment: Actually @jon, it only shows a breakdown if several off topic reasons where used. If voters pick different main close reasons, it's only shown the reason who won.

Comment: I think the main issue here is people may not want their name put against a reason they did not choose.

Comment: Jon Skeet can closehammer any question. He chooses not to.

Comment: Why hasn't this been fixed yet?

Answer (score 33):

The problem is that the wording of the message to the user is patently false. I see this as a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug).

The question was *not*

> **marked** as duplicate by Damien_The_Unbeliever, Jon Skeet, CodeCaster [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) 6 mins ago
>
> <sub>This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question.</sub>

The message should instead say something along the lines of:

> **This question was marked as a duplicate of an existing question.**
>
> <sub>The following users voted to put a hold on this question: Damien_The_Unbeliever, Jon Skeet, CodeCaster [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)</sub>

There are additional issues on top of the existing problem of the message being incorrect:

It emphasizes the wrong part of the message. Rather than calling out the people to blame, it should be calling out the reason the question was closed.

It states that the questions are "exact duplicates". In my experience, questions closed as duplicates are rarely, if ever, *exact* duplicates. This causes all sorts of problems for new members who feel the need to call out one of the blamed users (often myself) to complain about how their question about adding 2 + 3 is not *exactly* the same as the linked question adding 3 + 2, and therefor shouldn't be closed.

Comment: Yeah, I remember another FR asking deemphasize the people that closes a question vs the reason why it was closed.

Answer (score -8):

You say it's a problem that the OP doesn't know about the other close reasons, and, yes, I do see it's a problem. But the same problem occurs in many other situations!
I often find questions that are so bad I want to close them for multiple reasons, but I can only choose one. And then the OP won't know about the other things wrong with their message.

Unless of course, I add a comment mentioning all those things.

And if you really want, you can do that too, of course.

Comment: Yes, I can. But there were three close votes. Two of them were for (I suspect) the same reason, and yet the dupehammer overrode that and gave different feedback to the OP than the majority would have expected.

Comment: I know; that's what you said in the question. My answer was a way to get around that manually.